# Java Inheritance with generics extends

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

```
public interface Store<T> {
    Optional<List<? extends T>> method1();
}

public StoreImpl<R extends SomeType> implements Store<SomeType> {

    @Override
    public Optional<List<R>>    method1() {
        Optional<List<R>>  toReturn = Optional.empty();
           :
        toReturn = somePrivateMethodReturningListOfR();
           :
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Compiler cribs reporting incompatible return types for method1() between the interface and concrete implementation.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You don't need ```? extends``` Since T will be defined in the implementation

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I do not understand your suggestion. I want to be able to return a list of concrete objects extending T.

Comment: A dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265 `Optional<X>` is not assignable to `Optional<Y>`, even if `X` is assignable to `Y`, you'd need `Optional<? extends Y>` i.e. `Optional<? extends List<? extends T>>`.

Comment: You probably don't need the wildcard at all. You can put objects which extend `T` in a `List<T>`.